# Different sub-title for each page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

I am using VS 2010 and in the Site.Master page, there's a tag  which allows users to type in the title header.

E.g.

[image]

In this case, the title is 'ASP.NET Application'

I'd like to have a different title in every page of my application.

And I do this by adding this to site.master:

```
   <h1><%= Page.Title%></h1>
```

And in the code behind of each of my pages, I have something like this:

```
Page.Title = "My page title";
```

I'd like to add another sub-header to each of the page titles so that they sit just under the current header.

How would I go about that? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a public property to your master page:

```
public String SubTitle { get; set; }
```

And then you could add this to your markup:

```
<h2><%= ((YourMasterPage)Page.Master).SubTitle %></h2>
```

And in code behind:

```
((YourMasterPage)Page.Master).SubTitle = "My page sub title";
```

Answer (score 0):

Like MJ Hufford said you add

```
   //public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage in Site.master.cs
public static string SubTitle { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
   //your_page.aspx.cs
Page.Title = "My page title";
```

you write

```
  //your_page.aspx.cs
SiteMaster.SubTitle = "My SubTitle";
```

and finaly

```
  //your_page.aspx
<h2><%= MasterPage.SubTitle %></h2>
```

(Sorry for the re-writting, but it would helping me if it was written like this)